# Cast string to date in hive

Tags: hive

I'm am trying to convert the below string into a date in hive.  I have tried many of the solutions listed on stackoverflow, but have not found a reasonable solution yet.

3/10/21 18:46

Thanks for your help

Comment: please show your attempts

Comment: to_date(tx_time)  (tx_time is my column name with the string)

Comment: Have also tried from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(tx_time , 'dd-MM-yyyy'))

Comment: do you think your date has the format 'dd-MM-yyyy'? Why are you using that date format?

Comment: I'm not sure really.  Should I try 'mm-dd-yy' ?

Comment: try `M/d/yy HH:mm`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('3/10/21 18:46','dd/MM/yy HH:mm'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0sH7.png)